# What encoding am I using here when writing to disk via dbms_output.put_line?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, oracle11g

A vendor says the files I'm sending them are not **UTF-8** compliant.
Specifically, they say they can't read the following characters:

`í, á`

These are my Oracle 11g **NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS**

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  UTF8
NLS_CHARACTERSET        AL32UTF8
```

I'm writing to disk using **dbms_output.put_line**
After writing to disk, the characters appear fine when I 
grep them on a linux OS. I send the files to the vendor via **sftp** from a **linux OS**

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is the file I'm writing UTF8 compliant?
2. Given my Oracle configuration and the fact that I use dbms_output.put line, have I used the same encoding as if I had saved the file in MS Notepad with the UTF8 encoding option?

Comment: `dbms_output` doesn't write to disk; so how are you producing the text files - spool, redirtection, something else? What encoding does Notepad say the  files have, opening directly from wherever you're creating them, and after you transfer via sftp? What locale etc. do the machine you write to, and the one you sftp to, have? How are they looking at the files their end - have they ruled out their locale or tool or character set settings? Maybe they can send a file back to you by some other means, and you can see if it's still UTF-8 then.

Comment: It appears, a perl wrapper writes the file to disk after dbms_output runs. I was unfamiliar with the unix command `file`. I just ran `file -bi` and found my answer. Even though my Oracle environment is set, I still need to handle encoding once the file is on disk.